# Webpack error "Module build failed: ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm pretty new to react and am having some issues with web pack. All I'm trying to do is import a SVG file into my react project. I'm lost as to what is causing this as it doesn't give me much info about it. I would be grateful if anyone knows what's going on, thank you in advance lol.

***Error code in console:***

```
ERROR in ./src/img/flag/united-kingdom.svg
Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
    at Object.relative (path.js:437:5)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\sites\csgo\mern\client\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:78:72)
 @ ./src/components/header.js 12:0-74
 @ ./src/components/app.js
 @ ./src/app.js
```

***My webpack file (webpack.common.js)***

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        vender: [ 
            'react', 'react-dom', 'redux', 
            'react-redux', 'react-router-dom', 
            'axios', 'prop-types']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/'),
        filename: "js/[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },'sass-loader'],
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      outputPath: 'images/',
                      name: '[name][hash].[ext]',
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
              },
              {
                test: /\.(svg)$/,
                exclude: /fonts/, /* dont want svg fonts from fonts folder to be included */
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'svg-url-loader',
                    options: {
                      noquotes: true,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html')}),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'manifest',
            filename: "manifest.js",
            chunks: ['vender']
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'styles/style.css'
        }),
    ]
}
```

***Import code (literally all that references it):***

```
import { ReactComponent as UKFlag } from '../img/flag/united-kingdom.svg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem, changed my `file-loader` in `package.json` from `6.2.0` to `6.1.1` and it fixed it